# How to run a '.exe' File in parallel to your python script (Asynchrously)

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, subprocess, chess

I am working on a chess engine in which the engine I am using is stored in .exe file and the gui is made in python (pygame) and I want to access the engine (.exe file) through python for which I am using subprocess library.

The problem I am facing is that the chess engine needs to work continuosly without closing, the format is:

- input : e4
- output : e5

something like this, so based on user's input, I need to send the input to the engine and then capture the output to make the move.
I want my python script to run in parallel with the engine file while communicating with the engine back and fro, without closing the engine.

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.run('scid_windows_5.0.2\scid_windows_x64\engines\phalanx-scid.exe',shell=True,capture_output=True)
print(p1.stdout.decode())
```

Here, the output is only shown after the .exe file ends (ctrl + Z) and also i am unable to give input to the engine.
Please provide me a secure way of communicating with the engine while keeping the python script running.

Comment: Is the input supposed to be typed in? Try adding `input="e4".encode()` as a parameter to `run`.

Comment: We don't know enough about how this program works to give you an answer. I'd hope'd you take a minute for a test, but that didn't happen. If this program is meant to play an entire chess game with you making a move, it returning a move, and continuing, this would be done via paramiko or a pty on linux, but is harder on windows.

Comment: @tdelaney The Game is supposed to be a user vs CPU Game, so we have to wait till user make his move to forward his move to the engine and engine has to wait patiently till then without closing then take the response of the engine into our file and then again repeat, without closing the engine as it would make it lose its memory

Comment: 'Parallel (synchronously)' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess

# Create a process without blocking, redirect stdin and stdout into pipes
p = subprocess.Popen(["engine.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

#Send data to the process
p.stdin.write("e2\n".encode())
p.stdin.flush()
#Receive one line of data from the process (will block, if there is no input!)
answer = p.stdout.readline().decode()
```

Comment: No, this is not working,     *print(p1.stdin.readline().decode())
-io.UnsupportedOperation: read*, this error is showing up

Comment: @SujasKumarAggarwal I'm sorry, it should be `p1.stdout.readline().decode()`.

Comment: No, I am still unable to get the output in my main python file without closing the engine in back

Comment: @SujasKumarAggarwal I've tried the code with the engine. Seems two things are required: 1) you need to `.flush()` the stdin to actually send data 2) the commands must end with a newline (`\n`), otherwise it does not recognize them. I've edited the answer to reflect the changes.